# MicroStrategy 11 - Dossier

Tags: microstrategy

Is there the ability to Page by option in the MSTR Dossiers just like the grid report options?
I cant seem to find it. 'Page By' attribute.
I want to be able to export by attribute type on a separate page i.e Europe, ASIA, USA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sadly not possible. This can only be done directly on a web document. When exporting a dossier "Expand Page By" is not available as Page By is not available.

If you must use dossiers I suggest you duplicate your chapters as many times as you need and hardcode your page by elements on the filter. This is not standard and may become a maintenance nightmare.